# Where to load third party dependencies in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, requirejs

I want to use require.js in my webforms application.
The problem is there is no instructions in the require.js documentation on how to integrate AMD module loading with asp:ScriptManager modernizr bundles, Master and content pages, etc

Is it the case that require.js does not integrate very well with the webforms pattern, there seems to be better integration with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, where you drop this in will depend on how many pages you need, and do you have a "master" page, and then have used child pages for most of the site?

If you only going to use this for say 2-3 pages?

Then just drop the js script say into scripts folder.

so, I wanted to use a jquery "toast" message, and thus I
dropped in the js script for that like this:

[image]

So, now I can in the master page (site master) (if I want this for all pages), go:

Note how there is a section called "site scripts"

So, like this:

```
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />

            <%--Site Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.toast.min.js"/>
```

So, I added the 3rd party jquery.UI and jquery.toast to above.
(add under site scripts)

So, now I can say write in any web page this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="toast test"
    OnClientClick="GoGo2();return false;"/>

<script>
    function GoGo2() {
        $.toast({
            heading: "Working",
            text: 'Processing order #1234 -  - please wait',
            hideAfter: true,
            position: 'top-right',
            icon: 'info'
        })
    }
</script>
```

And I get this:

[image]

However, if you not use a site master page, then you have to add the scripts to each page, say like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="Scripts/jquery.toast.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.toast.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div style="margin:30px">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="toast test"
    OnClientClick="GoGo2();return false;"/>
</div>


<script>
    function GoGo2() {
        $.toast({
            heading: "Working",
            text: 'Processing order #1234 -  - please wait',
            hideAfter: true,
            position: 'top-right',
            icon: 'info'
        })
    }
</script>

</form>
</body>
```

(just drag + drop from script folder onto page), drop them in the top are (under head div section

So, where you should put the scripts depends on if your site uses a master page

Comment: Yes, but where would you reference require.is ?

Comment: Well, you add the  require.js (not .is) file into your scripts folder (use add existing file). At that point, you then have to include the script(s) in each web page in your project. As noted, either you add the script to the few pages you need, or you add it to site master page (if using), and then it is system wide for all pages. So add to project folder (scripts). Then just drag + drop the script from the project explore into the given page (up in the title section is fine).  or you can use script project wide if using a master page.

Comment: So you don't referance the .js file, you INCLUDE that script in the pages you to use that code. In above, I cover BOTH cases. Include in master page, if you want every page on the whole site to be able to use the script, or the 2nd example, we dragged jQuery and the custom add in (toast message) script into that single web page. So, if you not using a master page, and don't want to include the scripts in the master page, then  you doing this on a page by page choice - so the 2nd example shows were you include the scripts. you don't reference the scripts, you INCLUDE them in the pages.

Comment: Yes, but if I add require.js as a ScriptReference path, I then lose the use of the data-main attribute, because (presumably) I would'nt also reference it in the head section of Site.Master like this:
<script data-main="Scripts/main" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>

Comment: As a general rule you are able to drop in script refs into the master page, and all of that script code can freely be used in the child page without issue. this is how Everyone using asp.net and using script add-ins for 18 years now does this. If you have a specific example of some script code not working then start a new question with sample code showing what don't' work and we can hep you. I would try a blank test page and put the script refs at the top, but you can put the scripts in master page if using master pages and thus they will work on any page on the site that uses master page.

Comment: But no, I see no reason why you would lose reference of or use even of any variables that the given script library in question uses. How that particular library, or jQuery, or in my example jQuery.Toast library works is how this is done.